# How to download linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic?

Tags: apt, kernel, 18.10, linux-headers

> sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic is already the newest version (4.18.0-17.18).
linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
```

On installing linux-header it shows already the newest version but when I try to list the details it throw message No such file or directory?

> ls -l /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Couldn't you just reinstall the kernel headers by `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)` ?

Comment: The way to see what's in a package is with `dpkg -L linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic`. Or, run `pathlld` (https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?").